# How to mosaick two raster images (NDVI and NDWI) as one layer in GEE?

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, mosaic, google-earth-engine-python-api, folium

### Main gist (question)

I'm trying to mosaic **NDVI** and **NDWI** layers into one layer using **GEE** (python).
This is for having land part of the map covered by the NDVI results and the water part of the map covered by NDWI. All that in one layer.

Any idea how to make this work?

See here for reference: [Google Earth Engine: Image Visualization](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_visualization)

##### Visuals

| Wanted result | Similar to |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |
| Mosaic of NDWI & NDVI as one layer | Mosaic of NDWI & False Color Composite |

#### The problem

- Simply not working.
- No errors.
- "**Mosaic: NDWI x NDVI**" layer exist but not showing visuals.
- "**Clipped: NDWI x NDVI**" layer exist and only showing NDVI land part but in a grey scale colors, not original NDVI palette. The NDWI part of the mosaic is left out not showing.

| my actual results-1 (problem) | my actual results-2 (problem) |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |
| Clipped mosaic of NDWI & NDVI as one layer Greyed out and no NDWI | Nothing shows on the map (Mosaic of NDWI & NDVI not working) |

#### My approach

I first followed the official tutorial in GEE documentation (see here: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/image_visualization#mosaicking).

- Managed to reproduce the results and successfully mosaicked NDWI & FCC (false color composite) as one image layer.
- I tried to mosaic NDWI and NDVI but no results show up in that layer. No errors of execution in the console tho.

##### CODE:

```
import ee
import folium
from folium.raster_layers import TileLayer
import webbrowser

# trigger authentification
ee.Authenticate()

# initialize library
ee.Initialize()

# define method for displaying Earth Engine image tiles in folium maps
def add_ee_layer(self, ee_image_object, vis_params, name):
  map_id_dict = ee.Image(ee_image_object).getMapId(vis_params)
  folium.raster_layers.TileLayer(
      tiles = map_id_dict['tile_fetcher'].url_format,
      attr = 'Map Data &copy; <a href="https://earthengine.google.com/">Google Earth Engine</a>',
      name = name,
      overlay = True,
      control = True
  ).add_to(self)

# adding EE drawing method to folium
folium.Map.add_ee_layer = add_ee_layer

################## Landsat 8 Satellite Image 
image_sat = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA/LC08_044034_20140318')

################## FCC (False Color Composit) parameters
image_sat_viz_params = {
    'bands': ['B5', 'B4', 'B3'],
    'min': 0,
    'max': 0.5,
    'gamma': [0.95, 0.8, 1]
}

################## INDEX
# NDVI 
def getNDVI(image_sat):
  return image_sat.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4'])
ndvi= getNDVI(image_sat)

# visual params
ndvi_viz = {
  'min': 0,
  'max': 1,
  'palette': ['#ffffe5', '#f7fcb9', '#78c679', '#41ab5d', '#238443', '#005a32']
}

#NDWI
ndwi = image_sat.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B5'])
# visual params
ndwi_viz = {
    'min': 0.5,
    'max': 1,
    'palette': ['00FFFF', '0000FF']
}
################## Image Masking
# NDWI Masking: NDWI > 0.4
masked_ndwi = ndwi.updateMask(ndwi.gte(0.4))

# NDVI Masking: NDVI > 0
masked_ndvi = ndvi.updateMask(ndvi.gte(0))

################## Imge Visualization: transforming composit images to 8-bit RGB images
# FCC to image
image_rgb = image_sat.visualize(**{
  'bands': ['B5', 'B4', 'B3'],
  'max': 0.5
})

# NDVI to image
ndvi_rgb = ndvi.visualize(**{
    'min': 0,
    'max': 0.5,

})
# NDWI to image
ndwi_rgb = masked_ndwi.visualize(**{
    'min': 0.5,
    'max': 1,
    'palette': ['00FFFF', '0000FF']
})

################## Mosaicking
# e.g: NDWI and False Color Composit into a single layer.
mosaic_NDWI_FCC = ee.ImageCollection([image_rgb, ndwi_rgb]).mosaic()
mosaic_NDWI_NDVI = ee.ImageCollection([ndvi_rgb, ndwi_rgb]).mosaic()

##################  Clipping
# setting up the main region of interest perimeter (roi)
roi = ee.Geometry.Point([-122.4481, 37.7599]).buffer(20000)

# Clipped layers
clipped_NDWI_FCC = mosaic_NDWI_FCC.clip(roi)
clipped_NDWI_NDVI = masked_ndvi.clip(roi)

################## MAP SETUPS
# create folium map object
m = folium.Map(location=[37.7599, -122.6627], zoom_start=10)

basemap_dark = folium.TileLayer('cartodbdark_matter', name='Dark Matter')
basemap_dark.add_to(m)

################## COMPUTED LAYERS
# add the FCC, NDWI and NDVI layers to the map
m.add_ee_layer(image_sat, image_sat_viz_params, 'False Clors Composite')
m.add_ee_layer(ndwi, ndwi_viz, 'NDWI')
m.add_ee_layer(ndvi, ndvi_viz, 'NDVI')

# masked layers
m.add_ee_layer(masked_ndwi, ndwi_viz, 'Masked NDWI')
m.add_ee_layer(masked_ndvi, ndvi_viz, 'Masked NDVI')

# mosaicked layers
m.add_ee_layer(mosaic_NDWI_FCC, None, 'Mosaic: NDWI x FCC')
m.add_ee_layer(mosaic_NDWI_NDVI, None, 'Mosaic: NDWI x NDVI')

# clipped layers
m.add_ee_layer(clipped_NDWI_FCC, None, 'Clipped: NDWI x FCC')
m.add_ee_layer(clipped_NDWI_NDVI, None, 'Clipped: NDWI x NDVI')

##################
# adding layer controller 
folium.LayerControl(collapsed=False).add_to(m)

m.save('a-map.html')
webbrowser.open('a-map.html')
```

Comment: Hi Is this NDWI or NDMI ? In some places NDMI is mentioned

Comment: Ah thanks, I didn't realize spell mistakes. Originally I wanted to apply it to NDMI so I worked through the official GEE docs tutorial and used NDVI here just as a start.
Point is, I want to cover water area with NDWI on top of whatever other index I've got. (I edit fixed the post, thanks)